# Start drag action from a menu item

Tags: c++, qt

Given a `QTreeView` I would like to provide the user a means of inserting new items. For this I created a `QMenuBar` that contains several categorizing sub menus that in turn contain the different kinds of items the user can insert.

My first implementation was to select some existing item in the tree and then pick a menu item which is then inserted as a child of the selected item in the tree. There were buttons for rearranging the items, such as 'move up', 'move down' and so on. Later I replaced these buttons by a drag&drop interface where the user can simply drag items in the `QTreeView` around to rearrange them, which seems quite intuitive to me.

Now inserting new items into the tree by clicking menu items still feels annoying. In my opinion a more natural approach would be to *drag* the items out of the menu and into the desired location of the tree.

So is there a sensible way to implement this behaviour? My problem is how to start a drag operation by clicking a menu item as the `triggered()` signal is just emitted when the user releases the mouse button. But with the mouse button released, there is no drag anymore...

Comment: The easiest way would be to use some other item view as a source for dragging. See QtDesigner for example. Or do you have to use the menu?

Comment: I don't _absolutely_ have to use a menu. But it would be space efficient in that it does not occupy so much space of the screen.

Comment: Well, honestly I feel it would be easier for you to put an item view in a dock or popup widget for the user to drag from there. You could show your popup with item view on click on menu item thus not cluttering your UI. But I'd do that only if drag-and-dropping items from that menu is quite a rare operation. Otherwise a dock widget is more flexible and convenient. Clearly, I don't know your application so it's hard for me to argue about this.